# Python, complex looping calculations with lists or arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, while-loop

I am converting old pseudo-Fortran code into python and am struggling to create a framework within which I can perform some complex iterative calculations.

As a beginner, my first instinct is to use lists as I find them easier to work with, but i understand that arrays would probably be a more suitable method.

I already have all the input channels as lists and am hoping for a good explanation of how to set up loops for such calculations.

This is an example of the pseudo-Fortran i am replicating. Each (t) indicates a 'time-series channel' that I currently have stored as lists (ie. ECART2(t) and NNNN(t) are lists) All lists have the same number of entries.

```
do while ( ecart2(t) > 0.0002 .and. nnnn(t) < 2000. ) ;
    mmm(t)=nnnn(t)+1.;
    if YRPVBPO(t).ge.0.1 .and. YRPVBPO(t).le.0.999930338 .and. YAEVBPO(t).ge.0.000015 .and. YAEVBPO(t).le.0.000615 then do;
        YM5(t) = customFunction(YRPVBPO,YAEVBPO);*
    end;
    YUEVBO(t) = YU0VBO(t) * YM5(t) ;*m/s
    YHEVBO(t) = YCPEVBO(t)*TPO_TGETO1(t)+0.5*YUEVBO(t)*YUEVBO(t);*J/kg
    YAVBO(t) = ddnn2(t)*(YUEVBO(t)**2);*
    YDVBO(t) = YCPEVBO(t)**2 + 4*YHEVBO(t)*YAVBO(t) ;*
    YTSVBPO(t) = (sqrt(YDVBO(t))-YCPEVBO(t))/2./YAVBO(t);*K
    YUSVBO(t) = ddnn(t)*YUEVBO(t)*YTSVBPO(t);*m/s
    YM7(t) = YUSVBO(t)/YU0VBO(t);*
    YPHSVBPOtot(t) = (YPHEVBPO(t) - YPDHVBPO(t))/(1.+((YGAMAEVBO(t)-1)/2)*(YM7(t)**2))**(YGAMAEVBO(t)/(1-YGAMAEVBO(t)));*bar
    YPHEVBPOtot(t) = YPHEVBPO(t) / (1.+rss0(t)*YM5(t)*YM5(t))**rss1(t);*bar
    YDPVBPOtot(t) = YPHEVBPOtot(t) - YPHSVBPOtot(t) ;*bar
    iter(t) = (YPHEVBPOtot(t) - YDPVBPOtot(t))/YPHEVBPOtot(t);*
    ecart2(t)= ABS(iter(t)-YRPVBPO(t));*
    aa(t)=YRPVBPO(t)+0.0001;
    YRPVBPO(t)=aa(t);*
    nnnn(t)=mmm(t);*
end;
```

*Understanding the pseudo-fortran: With 'time-series data' there is an impicit loop iterating  through the individual values in each list - as well as looping over each of those values until the conditions are met.*

*It will carry out the loop calculations on the first list values until the conditions are met. It then moves onto the second value in the lists and perform the same looping calculations until the conditions are met...*

```
ECART2 = [2,0,3,5,3,4]
NNNN = [6,7,5,8,6,7]
do while ( ecart2(t) > 0.0002 .and. nnnn(t) < 2000. )
    MMM = NNNN + 1
```

this looks at the first values in each list (2 and 6). Because the conditions are met, subsequent calculations are performed on the first values in the new lists such as MMM = [6+1,...]

Once the rest of the calculations have been performed (looping multiple times if the conditions are not met) only then does the second value in every list get considered. The second values (0 and 7) do not meet the conditions and therefore the second entry for MMM is 0.

MMM=[6+1, 0...]

Because 0 must be entered if conditons are not met, I am considering setting up all the 'New lists' in advance and populating them with 0s.

NB: 'customFunction()' is a separate function that is called, returning a value from two input values

Comment: Take a look at numpy it is the tool for this sort of thing.  Also worth a look at Pandas.

Comment: I realise numpy arrays would be the best solution, but am not familiar  enough with them yet - hence my preference for lists and why i raised this question ;)

Thanks for the 'Pandas' suggestion, definitely something for me to investigate as i'm working exclusively with time-series data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY CURRENT SOLUTION

set up all the empty lists

```
nPts = range(ECART2)
MMM = [0]*nPts
YM5 = [0]*nPts
etc...
```

then start performing calculations

```
for i in ECART2:

    while (ECART2[i] > 0.0002) and (NNNN[i] < 2000):
        MMM[i] = NNNN[i]+1

        if YRPVBPO[i]>=0.1 and YRPVBPO[i]<=0.999930338 and YAEVBPO[i]>=0.000015 and YAEVBPO[i]<=0.000615:
            YM5[i] = MACH_LBP_DIA30(YRPVBPO[i],YAEVBPO[i])

        YUEVBO[i] = YU0VBO[i]*YM5[i]
        YHEVBO[i] = YCPEVBO[i]*TGETO1[i] + 0.5*YUEVBO[i]^2
        YAVBO[i] = DDNN2[i]*YUEVBO[i]^2
        YDVBO[i] = YCPEVBO[i]^2 + 4*YHEVBO[i]*YAVBO[i]
        etc etc...
```

but i'm guessing that there are better ways of doing this - such as the suggestion to use numpy arrays (something i plan on learning in the near future)